# HOW TO Resizing a bimap without createBitmap to avoid oom issue

Tags: android, bitmap, resize, out-of-memory

after researching, i only find InSampleSize to resize a bitmap

but i am looking for something that'll allow me to resize the bitmap to large or smaller depends on the screen resolution

since bitmap.createBitmap will result OOM, i have to use something else...

please help

here is the code where i resize my bitmap which result 5mb~10mb bump each time i resize anybitmap

```
Bitmap createdBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to get the screen that is currently running on:

```
@Override
public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
{
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    screenW = w;
    screenH = h;
}
```

and then use this to load the bitmap so you are loading it into memory reasonably:

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
        int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
        int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
        String imageType = options.outMimeType;
        if(imageWidth > imageHeight){
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,screenH,screenW);

        }else{
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,screenW,screenH);

        }
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath,options);
```

method:

```
public int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
    final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
    final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

    // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
    // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
    // requested height and width.
    inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
}

return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: do what you want just remember that i think its 16MB per app heap memory, say a regular camerashot is alot of memory as a full bitmap, say the device is 480X320 load as that instead of full res, too many youll overload

Comment: and you cant Bitmap.createBitmap then createScaledBitmap?

Comment: Bitmap.createBitmap will increase 5mb per bitmap... createScaledBitmap doesn't help either...
btw... only on some devices createBitmap and createScaleBitmap will have this crazy increase on memory. mostly it worked fine..  "some device" include android 2.3~4.1, or screen from 3"~10"... nor simulator will have this problem

Comment: bitmaps take alot of memory, they use the fully uncompressed size, you got to be carefull, i dont know what to tell you other than theres no need to go over the actual devices size when scaling them, even then only a couple, you have to manage them right

Comment: by manage... what do you mean... after hours of research.. i am not getting anywhere :(

Comment: when your done with it recycle(), watch all your static members, only use what is neccessary